# Are U-19 youth international test match(3days) includes in one"s First class career?

Tags: cricket

Are U-19 youth international test match (3 days) includes in one"s First class career?

Answer (score 3):

No, age-group teams up to U19 cannot play first-class cricket. This is clearly stated in the document [ICC Classification of Official Cricket](http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_FCD120A8291EE652F940541A07661A2C_1274949685555_215.pdf), on page 3, in the Notes to the First-class Matches section:

> Matches involving age-group teams up to and including U19 shall not be
>   classified as First-Class matches

Note also that despite bearing the name "Youth Tests", age-group international multi-day matches are not classified as Test matches, as the document makes clear:

> Matches involving an 'A' team or age-group team shall not be
>   classified as Test matches